# Pausing and resuming a Mediawiki edit session

Tags: session, cookies, mediawiki, edit

Is it possible to pause and resume a Mediawiki edit?

To explain, I've written a MW extension that accesses an external database; this database requires OAuth authentication, which is a three-step process requiring the user to be redirected to an external site to allow the extension access to the external db. If the MW extension already has an access token for the extDb, all is well. However, if there isn't a token, there is a problem. This is a tag extension, and is triggered by finding a certain XML tag in the wiki page, which typically occurs in the 'preview' or 'submit' of an edit, e.g. http://server.com/wiki/index.php?title=Bibliography&action=submit (the parser hook is [ParserFirstCallInit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ParserFirstCallInit)). The callback URL constructed by the OAuth code returns you to the page you were editing, but in its pre-edit state: i.e. you lose all your edits.

How can I resume the edit and not lose my edit data?

Comment: Does this feature resemble the (now removed) external editors sytem? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:External_editors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use store the data in [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).  MediaWiki itself uses it to store user authentication data, so it should be well integrated with MediaWiki's own session handling.

Note that, by default, MediaWiki doesn't create a session for anonymous users unless they try to log in or do something else that requires a session.  If your external authentication code is only meant to be used by logged-in users, this should not be an issue, but just to be safe you may want to make sure that a session is set up before trying to use it:

```php
if ( session_id() == '' ) {
    wfSetupSession();
}
```

Comment: Only logged in users can edit this wiki, so that is fine.

I'm not very familiar with the mediawiki core; can you suggest any URL parameters that can be used to trigger the loading of a specific session via a callback URL, e.g. http://wiki.com/index.php?action=load&session=<session_id>? I had a look at the parameters for index.php but couldn't see anything that fitted.

Comment: Um... I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your callback.  PHP (and thus MediaWiki) sessions are normally loaded based on cookies, so as long as the user has cookies enabled, they should just work. It _is_ possible to [pass the session ID as a URL parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) too, but that's generally not recommended (for good security reasons) and I don't see why you'd need to do that.

Comment: I want to resume the edit that I interrupted to visit the third-party site (see the original Q).

Comment: I understand that, but you shouldn't need to include session IDs in the URL to do that.  Instead, just generate a unique ID with something like `$id = uniqid()`, save the edited text in `$_SESSION['myExtSavedEdits'][$id]` and include the `$id` in the callback URL (e.g. `?action=edit&resume_edit=$id`).  Then, in some suitable hook, look for it with `$request->getVal('resume_edit')` (where `$request` is a WebRequest object) and, if found, use it to prefill the edit form.

Comment: Ps. There's a bunch of edit metadata you may want to save in the session in addition to the text, like the page being edited and the starting time of the edit (for edit conflict detection).